# How to perform a JOIN over two virtual tables in Superset?

Tags: sql, apache-superset

In SQL Lab View I can create a complex query by joining two **physical** datasets together with a simple inner join (supported by the underlying database). However, when I create two **virtual** datasets I can't find a way to join them. How do I reference a virtual dataset in SQL Lab View?

I have read Superset docs about ["using virtual datasets"](https://preset.io/blog/understanding-superset-semantic-layer/#using-virtual-datasets) and they provide the same use case as mine.

> So when should you use a virtual dataset? Here are some use cases with
> some concrete examples.
>
> Joining multiple tables (or self-joining against the same table) To
> visualize total revenue by customer persona, we need to JOIN between a
> customers table and an orders table to form the customers_orders
> virtual dataset.

What they do not provide is an example of how do it. I have tried to reference a virtual table just by its name but no luck:

```
SELECT *
FROM "My Virtual Table"
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Don't forget to identify the schema you've place the virtual table into. aka `FROM schema.my_virtual_table`

Comment: What schema I should use? Using the same schema as the physical dataset is wrong: 
`druid error: Plan validation failed (org.apache.calcite.tools.ValidationException): org.apache.calcite.runtime.CalciteContextException: From line 1, column 15 to line 1, column 48: Object 'My Virtual Table' not found within 'druid'`

Comment: Note that tables are different from physical datasets (the dataset has extra metadata, metrics, derived columns). You can join two tables together in SQL Lab, and build a virtual dataset from the query. But you can't write a join using datasets, neither virtual nor physical.

I have a PR open (https://github.com/apache/superset/pull/15241) that allows querying datasets and would allow you to join them (as long as they're in the same DB), let me do another pass on it.

Comment: Looks promising!

Comment: Now that https://github.com/apache/superset/pull/15241 is merged and available in 2.0, how do I join two virtual dataset?

Comment: I still can't seem to get two virtual datasets to be joined. Did anyone fine a solution?